# rsync creating duplicate files

Tags: files, rsync, duplicate

rsync is creating duplicate files on destination and renaming them. Filename.txt gets added again as Filename(1).txt

rsync -avP --ignore-existing /source/ /destination/

Anyone have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Where is the destination? Is is it a remote folder? If remote, how is it connected, sftp, NFS, Samba, or some other means? What is the format type of the remote file system, ext4, NTFS, or something else? If it is an external USB drive, what is the partition format?

Comment: `--ignore-existing` does what it says in `man rsync`: it will not update existing files. If a file with the same name already exists in the destination, it needs to rename the newly arriving file.

Comment: Distro is Ubuntu 22.04 / copy is from remote cifs vers=3.3 share to remote NFS vers=4 share

Comment: My quick tip for --ignore-existing says it will skip existing files. Did not elaborate on full def in man rsync. Could be my issue. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Nope, that was not the issue. Still seeing duplicated files with the --ignore-existing removed.